# How can I set my view to take top half of the screen for react-native android app?

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I want to set my `<View>` to take only the top half of the screen. If I set `flex:1` on the view's style, it will take the full screen. See below code:

```
render(){
  return(
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
       ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have tried to set the flex value to 0.5 but it doesn't help. How can I set my view takes half of the screen on flexbox?

Answer (score 2):

```
render(){
  return(
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={{flex:.5}}>
       ...
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:.5}}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer.

Comment: Whoever down voted this, this is the way React Native recommends for this type of setting. *sigh*

Comment: @sfratini I down voted because the answer was provided after mine and is pretty much exactly the same. Putting .5 instead of 1 makes no difference because the calculation is identical. As a matter of fact, it could confuse people because no context was provided. The value you provide as the flex is arbitrary as long as that value divided by the total within the scope is what you want. Specifying .5 does not mean half the screen. It works here because .5 / (.5 + .5) = .5 / 1 = .5. But none of that was explained.

Comment: @TheJizel in that case your answer is also wrong because you are adding text into the second View while it is supposed to be a filler. Anyway, I don't think that is a reason to downvote but that is OK.

Comment: @sfratini Ok, I explained why my answer works and what the reasoning behind that was. Obviously, the text elements were not to be taken as the literal answer. Was I supposed to write the code for him? Also - if we are being completely literal, your answer is completely wrong. He asked for flexbox, not Dimensions. So which is it? Try to give people an inch and they want a mile. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```html
<View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'powderblue',height:100}} />
    <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'skyblue',height:100}} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const height = Dimensions.get('window').height*0.5;
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
       width,
       height
   }
)};

render(){
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
       ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer and works well with different sizes of screens and devices

Answer (score -1):

Another way is you can use the Dimensions API to check the Height of the device and set the component height to half and position absolute: [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html)